# Path Error using Python 3 in Sublime Text

Tags: python, path, sublimetext3

I have a struggle using this editor. I tried it a year ago and after some hair-pulling, ended up leaving it for another platform. I came back today, and I want to fix my problem and go farther than just step one.

I got a picture of my code and will provide the code written out here as well. I will also be providing a picture of the book I am using (Python Crash Course 2nd Edition) with the instructions given to me.

If any more info is needed, or some clarification. Please let me know. I want to get moving past this obstacle.

[Picture of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGSDq.png)

```
print("Hello Python World!")

[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd: ['python3', '-u', 'C:\\Users\\2\\Desktop\\New folder\\Coding\\python\\python_work\\hello_world.py']]
[dir: C:\Users\2\Desktop\New folder\Coding\python\python_work]
[path: C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\2\Desktop\Python\Python310;C:\Users\2\Desktop\Python\Python310\Scripts;C:\Users\2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\;C:\Users\2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\;C:\Users\2\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.3.1\bin;]
[Finished]
```

[Picture of Directions from Book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McCO0.jpg) (pg 10)

```
{
"cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file"],
}
```

---

```
print("Hello Python World!")
```

---

```
Hello Python World!
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

---

Once again, if any clarification or extra detail is needed, just let me know and I will clarify to the best of my ability.

[Problem solved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pjVi.jpg)

Ended up switching the build system from Python3 to Python and removed the cmd directions from the book. Problem fixed. Big thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The instructions in your book are either out of date or flat out misleading you; I would not recommend following them.

You only need to create your own `sublime-build` file to execute a Python program as Python version 3 if you're running Sublime Text 3 ***AND*** you are on Linux/MacOS.

The `Python.sublime-build` file that ships with ST3 will execute `python.exe` by default on Windows which (if you have Python installed and on the `PATH`) will work. The version of the file that ships with ST4 executes the `py.exe` helper on Windows, which is always available on the `PATH` and will find the right version of Python for you no matter where it's installed (so long as it is in fact installed).

Using the name `python3` is required only on Linux and MacOS, for which the name `python` refers to Python 2 and not Python 3 (and it does not exist on Windows at all, which is the ultimate source of your problem). In ST3 the build always tries to execute `python` on these platforms, but in ST4 the default is now `python3`.

The build as outlined in the book doesn't set up an appropriate `selector` to allow the build to be auto selected or a `file_regex` to match errors to allow for error navigation. Perhaps later parts of the book include that; the built in build supports it directly out of the box.

In any case, the most expedient way to test out your code would be to select `Python` under `Tools > Build Systems` and then run the build again. Sublime is going to ask you if you want the `Python` or the `Python - Syntax Check` build; choose the first one in the list.

The `Syntax Check` variant only compiles your code but doesn't actually run it, which is almost never want you want.

If that works, you can delete your `sublime-build` file and change the selected build to `Automatic`, which will cause Sublime to pick the Python build for you automatically so long as you execute the build while you're editing a Python file.

Comment: So the problem looks like it was because the book was outdated? 2nd time that has happened to me. Dunno if you are still here or not, Im still going to continue with my current book since I am just starting it and I want to see how much I can get from it. Any python books that you have read that you might recommend to a beginner like myself? Preferably up to date if possible hah. You (OdatNurd) or anyone else viewing this comment.

Comment: I don't have any specific advice about Python books, no; I'm not sure what book you're looking at here but the main point of concern would be it's coverage of how to set up Sublime to execute Python code directly. Apart from that it's advice on using Python may still be quite valid.

Comment: I'm the author of Python Crash Course. There's a paragraph immediately before the page shared here that says you only need to do this configuration if your system uses the `python3` command, or any command other than `python`. I don't have any issue with OP asking this question, it's an easy thing to miss if this is your first time working with an editor. I just want to clarify that the book is still up to date at this point.

Comment: Another thing to miss, I gotta pay more attention. I said im still going to read it, I got people recommending the book to this day, just have times like this that adds some doubt.

Comment: Took a 2nd look at that paragraph. I didnt understand what was meant by running the "python command". We ran python in the terminal session, followed the instructions, had a visual... easy, I knew that, just didnt know if we ran a python command in the terminal session. Something that I didnt understand.

Comment: @japhyr I have an issue with that page - you instruct readers to save `hello_world.py`, then enter `print("Hello World")`, then run the build system. I would strongly suggest instructing them to save the file again before running, otherwise nothing will show up on the output panel (it's not a terminal, as you can't interact with it). Running a build system runs the last *saved* version of a file, not necessarily what's currently shown on-screen. Finally, with ST4, the built-in Python build system works out of the box on all OSes, so there is no need to create a separate Python 3 build system.

Comment: `Tools > Save all on build` is turned on by default, but it's worth a mention that you want it turned on if it's not, and that you need to manually save a new file first (if for no other reason than to set the syntax); I don't know if the book mentions that and/or if you're working on another draft or not though.

Comment: @MattDMo @OdatNurd I really appreciate you each weighing in. Often these posts are just me and a reader. Writing chapter 1 of an intro book is hard; writing instructions in printed form that should work for everyone, with some "if this doesn't work" clauses, is a balancing act. When hundreds of thousands of people read the book, people find the edge cases. I never had this issue because I think `Save all on build` has always been on in my own setups. And I get this question once every 6 months, so I think it's on for most people.

Comment: I have people save first so they get syntax highlighting, and because it's such a good habit to start out with a saved file. I can't update the printed book, but I'll add a note in the online resources to check that `Save all on build` is on. Also, I'll try ST4 on a fresh macOS VM and update the resources to reflect the newer approach as well. It's been really nice to see tools evolve to require less configuration over the years.

Comment: @japhyr At least with ST4, "Save All on Build" is checked by default, so that's probably helping a lot of people.